# How to use cogs from multiple directories - Discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

Would it be possible to use cogs from different folders, for example `commands/` and `economy_commands/`.

My code is

```
    for extension in os.listdir('commands/') and os.listdir('economy_commands/'):
        if extension.endswith('.py'):
            print('loaded ' + extension)
            client.load_extension(f'commands.{extension[:-3]}')
    print('----------')
```

I get thrown the error `discord.ext.commands.errors.ExtensionNotFound: Extension 'commands.create_player_bank' could not be loaded.`

`create_player_bank` is located in `economy_commands`. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You need to use `client.load_extension(f'economy_commands.{extension[:-3]}')` for cogs saved in that folder. Consider splitting your `for ... and ...` into two `for ...` statements

Comment: This worked. If you could, could you make it as an answer so other people can view it easier. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Credit to Benjin's comment, this isn't my solution. Just for people to see easier

**You need to use client.load_extension(f'economy_commands.{extension[:-3]}') for cogs saved in that folder. Consider splitting your for ... and ... into two for ... statements**